# Why do my gvfs mounts not show up under ~/.gvfs or /run/user/<login>/gvfs?

Tags: gnome, nautilus, filesystem, mount, gvfs

From what I read, when mounting a network share via nautilus or `gvfs-mount` the mount point should be in `~/.gvfs`. This seems not to be the case for me: I tried mounting both an FTP and SMB share via both nautilus and `gvfs-mount` under both Ubuntu Maverick and Natty and in none of the cases did I see any mount point under `~/.gvfs`. I can access the shares just find in nautilus, but I want to have access via the command line, which is why I need a mount point in the file system.

**Edit:** Debugging following James Henstridge's answer and enzotib's comment revealed that on my laptop `gvfs-fuse-daemon` is running and consequently gvfs mounts show up in `~/.gvfs`, whereas on the 2 workstations where `~/.gvfs` remained empty `gvfs-fuse-daemon` was not running. On all 3 machines there are other gvfs processes running: `gvfsd`, `gvfs-afc-volume-monitor`, ...

On the laptop, `mount | fgrep gvfs` yields

```
gvfs-fuse-daemon on /home/xxx/.gvfs type fuse.gvfs-fuse-daemon (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=xxx)
```

That raises the questions:

- How are shares mounted without `gvfs-fuse-daemon` running? Is there no mount point created in that case and is every access to the share a gvfs library call? Which daemon is responsible? `gvfsd`?
- What's the role of `gvfs-fuse-daemon`? Does it only create a fuse mount point in `~/.gvfs`?

**Update:** On 12.10 and later, mounts are under `/run/user/<login>/gvfs`.

Comment: Can you show the output of `mount | grep gvfs`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `~/.gvfs` directory should be a FUSE mount handled by the `gvfs-fuse-daemon` process.  If the directory appears to be empty, it would indicate that `gvfs-fuse-daemon` did not start correctly.

You could try starting it manually with the following command:

```
/usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-fuse-daemon ~/.gvfs
```

If that fails, you could try checking whether anything else is mounted there, or even delete and recreate the ~/.gvfs directory first.  If things still fail, could you update your question and provide any error messages printed by `gvfs-fuse-daemon`?

** On 14.04 the daemon is called `gvfsd-fuse` and can be found in `/usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-fuse`.

Comment: Some more [research](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=78339) revealed that `gvfsd` is supposed to start `gvfs-fuse-daemon` automatically when `gvfsd` gets the first request to access a remote file system. There's also a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gvfs/+bug/212789) in ubuntu/debian that makes the `~/.gvfs` directory unreadable when `gvfs-fuse-daemon` crashes and produces the error message _Transport endpoint is not connected_.

Comment: Was it ever resolved why `gvfsd` does not start `gvfs-fuse-daemon` automatically?  Under RHEL it seems to work as expected for root but not unprivileged users.

Comment: Doesn't really answer the question of "What's the role of gvfs-fuse-daemon", and "How are shares mounted without gvfs-fuse-daemon running?". gvfs-fuse-daemon allows options like allow_root which are ignored by default when using gvfs-mount. So answering those questions would kinda help solve this eternal mystery here.

Comment: There is another caveat! `gvfs-mount` requires DBUS and you will only get a mountpoint when `gvfs-mount` uses _THE SAME DBUS SESSION_ as `gvfs-fuse-daemon`. Therefore, if you are SSHing into a machine and firing up a `dbus-daemon` for your session you also have to spawn an individual `gvfs-fuse-daemon` for your session.

Comment: Well, it's 5 years later and this still seems to be an issuel

Answer (score 21):

Solved the problem (kind of).

On Ubuntu 12.10 the mountpoint appears in `/run/user/(your username)/gvfs/sftp\:host\=\192.168.xxx.xxx`.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 4):

In Ubuntu 12.10 the paths were changed:

```
$ mount |grep gvfs
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/pcm/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=pcm)
```

Answer (score 4):

In newer versions of Ubuntu, gvfs defaults to mounting in `/run/user/$USER/gvfs/`.

You can check yourself where it's default mount point is by looking for your user's gvfsd-fuse line in `/etc/mtab`.

Answer (score 3):

I have a similar problem with my 12.04 Precise system.

Drives that appear mounted in Nautilus do not appear in `~/.gvfs`, particularly after a suspend/resume cycle. `gvfs-fuse-daemon` is running, but killing it and restarting does not fix the problem.

I found that restarting Nautilus after `nautilus -q` causes `gvfs-fuse-daemon` and Nautilus to co-operate again - the mount points reappear.

Answer (score 3):

On Debian 6.0 wheezy, with lxde and nautilus.
I found the ~/.gvfs directory empty too. I tried to run

```
/usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-fuse-daemon ~/.gvfs
```

But it told me: /dev/fuse: Permission Denied.

```
$ ll /dev/fuse
crw-rw---T 1 root fuse 10, 229 Dec 21 11:59 /dev/fuse
```

I thought that maybe it's because I'm not in the fuse group, then I added my user account to that group.
After a reboot, the gvfs mount shows in ~/.gvfs correctly.

Answer (score 3):

I [asked a related question](https://superuser.com/q/717893/79304) for my Debian system, and the [answer](https://superuser.com/a/720528/79304) was to:

```
apt-get install gvfs-fuse
adduser <username> fuse
```

Then reboot. After a GVFS mount (via Nautilus), the share directory will be in one of two places, depending on which version of Debian or Ubuntu you have:

```
/run/user/<username>/gvfs
~/.gvfs
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't have to reboot. A ``systemctl --user restart gvfs-daemon`` did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

When I want to access files shared from a Windows machine directly (not browsing through Nautilus) I mount the share on a folder in my home directory.

For example. There if there is a Windows machine with the IP address `192.168.16.2` on the domain `mydomain` that has a folder shared as `shared` and I have a directory in my home directory called `mnt`, I can mount the share on`mnt` and access it as if it was within my home directory with:

```
sudo mount -t cifs "//192.168.16.2/shared" /home/stacey/mnt -o credentials=credentials,uid=stacey,gid=stacey
```

where credentials contains:

```
username=stacey
password=mypassword
domain=mydomain
```

Now I can use `ls /home/stacey/mnt` to list the files and directories in shared directory `shared` on `192.168.16.2` and access any file within this mount point as I would a file on my local hard drive.

You can get more information on mounting SMB shares with:

```
man mount.cifs
```

Comment: Not what the OP asked.

Comment: No, but kynan said "but I want to have access via the command line, which is why I need a mount point in the file system", so I'm just trying to help.

Comment: Thanks. I should have mentioned that I have considered this solution, but it imho has 2 major downsides that make it infeasible: 1) the credentials file must contain the password in plain text, which is unacceptable on a shared machine, 2) it requires root privileges and I need a solution that also works on machines where I don't have sudo

Answer (score 0):

For now...

```
#!/bin/bash
# Add to Cron
# */1 * * * * /root/fixGvfs
w | grep -v root | tail -n +3 | awk '{print $1}' > /tmp/fixGvfsUsers
while read usuario
do
  id=$(id -u $usuario)
  if [ ! -f "/tmp/fixGvfs${id}" ]; then
    umount /run/user/${id}/gvfs
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
      su - $usuario -c "/usr/bin/pkill gvfs*"
      touch "/tmp/fixGvfs${id}"
    fi
  fi
done < /tmp/fixGvfsUsers
```

Comment: A short explanation what this script is going to do would be nice. When the cron-job should run?