# Command line method to find disk usage of camera mounted using gvfs

Tags: command-line, disk-usage, gvfs

When my camera was mounted on `/media` I could use the standard tools (`df`) to see the disk usage of the card in my camera. However now the camera is mounted using gvfs, and df seems to ignore it. I've also tried pydf and discus to no avail.

The camera is definitely available through nautilus, and when I select the camera in nautlius, the status bar tells me the amount of disk free. I can also open the `~/.gvfs/` folder in nautilus and right click on the camera folder and get the disk usage in a graphical way.

But that is no use for a script. Are there command line tools that are the equivalent of `df` for gvfs filesystems? Or even better, a way to make `df` report on gvfs filesystems?

Comment: Check out this [question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/61196/why-do-my-gvfs-mounts-not-show-up-under-gvfs). `gvfs-fuse-daemon` might be the workaround for this issue.   This is a know [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/lightdm/+bug/867806)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some poking around and discovered [gvfs-info](http://www.unix.com/man-page/OpenSolaris/1/gvfs-info/) does what I need.

```
$ gvfs-info -f ~/.gvfs/gphoto2\ mount\ on\ usb%3A002,005/
attributes:
  filesystem::size: 16017719296
  filesystem::free: 4316299264
  filesystem::type: gphoto2
  filesystem::readonly: FALSE
  filesystem::use-preview: 1
  gvfs::backend: gphoto2
```

Interestingly, hitting <kbd>Tab</kbd> at the command line changed the above command into:

```
gvfs-info -f gphoto2://[usb:002,005]/
```

Which gave exactly the same information. I did a little experiment and found that plugging the camera into a different port gave a different address, but doing a `ls` of `~/.gvfs/` would find the camera.