# Where ".gvfs" has gone in 14.04

Tags: networking, samba, gvfs

My question is "simple".

Where can I find a local mount point for the Samba shares I'm connected to. In 12.04 it was located under `*home/.gvfs*`.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Here is my smb.conf file :

```
#======================= Global Settings =======================

[global]
workgroup = mshome
server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
dns proxy = no
log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
max log size = 1000
    syslog = 0
    panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
encrypt passwords = no
obey pam restrictions = yes
unix password sync = yes
passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
pam password change = yes
    map to guest = bad user
    usershare allow guests = yes
    comment = Home Directories
    browseable = no
    read only = no
security = user
username map = /etc/samba/smbusers

[printers]
    comment = All Printers
    browseable = no
    path = /var/spool/samba
    printable = yes
;   guest ok = no
;   read only = yes
    create mask = 0700
# Windows clients look for this share name as a source of downloadable
# printer drivers

[print$]
    comment = Printer Drivers
    path = /var/lib/samba/printers
;   browseable = yes
;   read only = yes
;   guest ok = no
# Uncomment to allow remote administration of Windows print drivers.
# You may need to replace 'lpadmin' with the name of the group your
# admin users are members of.
# Please note that you also need to set appropriate Unix permissions
# to the drivers directory for these users to have write rights in it
;   write list = root, @lpadmin
# A sample share for sharing your CD-ROM with others.

;[cdrom]
;   comment = Samba server's CD-ROM
;   read only = yes
;   locking = no
;   path = /cdrom
;   guest ok = yes
# The next two parameters show how to auto-mount a CD-ROM when the
#   cdrom share is accesed. For this to work /etc/fstab must contain
#   an entry like this:
#
#       /dev/scd0   /cdrom  iso9660 defaults,noauto,ro,user   0 0
#
# The CD-ROM gets unmounted automatically after the connection to the
#
# If you don't want to use auto-mounting/unmounting make sure the CD
#   is mounted on /cdrom
#
;   preexec = /bin/mount /cdrom
;   postexec = /bin/umount /cdrom

[RED]
    comment = RED USB Disk
    path = /media/laurent06000/RED
    writeable = yes
;   browseable = yes
    guest ok = yes

[flareGet]
    path = /home/laurent06000/flareGet
    writeable = yes
;   browseable = yes
    guest ok = yes

[windows]
    comment = Windows Main drive
    path = /media/windows
    writeable = yes
;   browseable = yes
    guest ok = yes
```

Comment: Please, mark an answer as correct if some of them solves your problem

Answer (score 11):

Thanks to LewisTM, you can find your `gvfs` folder in `/run/user/$UID/gvfs`.

```
$ mount | grep gvfs
```

Also see [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2073288&s=a19d73e2b26158ee28330927102536dc&p=12305478#post12305478).

Comment: This is not the case for me - I do not even have a `.gvfs` folder. Where would the samba share be mounted, when mounted with nautilus?

Comment: I would suggest symlinking (`ln -s /run/user/$UID/gvfs ~/.gvfs`) to that folder rather than returning to this answer every time like I have done too many times to count.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't have `.gvfs` any longer, you should be able to find the gvfs mount location with `mount | grep gvfs`. For example, 
`gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=nrd)` .

The location is there, and you can pull it out programmatically if you want, with `mount | grep gvfs | awk '{print $3}'` or something similar.   The example here just returns `/run/user/1000/gvfs`.

If you are pre-12.10, you should have `~/.gvfs`, but after 12.10 look in /run/user/*user_id*/gvfs/ .
 If `~/.gvfs` already was present (which would happen if you upgraded from an earlier release), it won't be clobbered in new releases, but the new directory will be created anyway.

You can find your uid in a few different way, e.g., by looking in `/etc/passwd`, or running `id --user` or `echo "$UID"`.

The new location would then be `/run/user/$(id --user)/gvfs/`

In my system, the $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR variable also contains the directory above gvfs:

```
$ env | grep user
[...]
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
```

So, on my system, I have `/run/user/1000/gvfs`.

Also see 
[Why do my gvfs mounts not show up under ~/.gvfs or /run/user/<login>/gvfs?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61196/why-do-my-gvfs-mounts-not-show-up-under-gvfs-or-run-user-login-gvfs)

Comment: Thanks a lot heemayl and belacqua (with a bit of delay - I was not used o the askubuntu process) but THIS was what I wanted to know. Very useful !!!

Comment: I wanted a command line script to access a remote samba share mounted by entering a smb:// url in nautilus address bar. In previous versions of Ubuntu a mount point for such urls was created in ~/.gvfs, I lost track of the new location through the years. Thanks you. I can confirm the new location remains the same for 15.04, 15.10 and 16.04.

Answer (score 0):

It's just inside your `$HOME` directory.

```
$ locate .gvfs
/home/avinash/.gvfs
```

Comment: Thanks for tour help. I Finally downgraded to 13.10 for some time.