# Gvfs folder location in Ubuntu Mate 15.04

Tags: samba, 15.04, mate, gvfs, location

Despite this question [Where ".gvfs" has gone in 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/453387/where-gvfs-has-gone-in-14-04) , the folder I found in `/run/user/1000/gvfs` is empty, but I have 3 mounted samba shares.

Even `locate .gvfs` gives no results and all `locate gvfs` results don't have any of the mounted samba shares inside.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem and VLC wouldn't play videos from a smb mount.  To solve this I installed gvfs-fuse - which was not installed by default.

```
sudo apt-get install gvfs-fuse
```

`/run/user/1000/gvfs` will contain your samba mounts after you install gvfs-fuse.  You will need to reboot after installing.

I added a bug report here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-mate/+bug/1456803

Comment: You can [edit] your answer (and any other answer in this site) to incorporate further info...  **;-)**  And welcome on board!