# Where is the GVFS folder in 15.04

Tags: mount, 15.04, samba, gvfs

I can't seem to locate the GVFS folder in Ubuntu 15.04 has its location changed from 14.10?

The old location:

```
/run/user/1000/gvfs/
```

Is always empty, no matter how many samba shares are mounted. [image: View of gvfs folders showing empty despite a samba share being mounted.]

So has the location moved? The reason that I ask is that I am having problems playing video and music files from Samba shares since upgrading from 14.10 to 15.04 and I am guessing that gvfs is the cause.

I have tried another answer that suggested that I install gvfs-fuse, but this was already installed - a re-installation didn't help.

I guess a second question would be if the location is the same, why isn't anything mounting there anymore?

Comment: Have a look at this thread http://askubuntu.com/questions/620584/gvfs-folder-location-in-ubuntu-mate-15-04.

Comment: Thanks, I looked at that but it seems that gvfs-fuse is installed by default on Ubuntu 15.04 and is installed on my system. I tried re-installing but this didn't make any difference. The gvfs folder is still empty even after a restart.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a confirmed bug in the gvfs package:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gvfs/+bug/1451087

a workaround at this moment is to first kill both gvfs deamons before trying to mount.

To do so just execute the command:

```
killall gvfsd
```

from a terminal.

Now you can find your mountpoint again in:

> /run/user/XXXX/gvfs

Comment: I got this to work by running `fusermount -uz /run/user/XXXX/gvfs` disconnecting the phone, `killall gvfsd` and then reconnecting.