# Where is the smb mount point in 15.10 of shares mounted via the file manager?

Tags: mount, permissions, nautilus, samba, gvfs

From Ubuntu 15.10 I want to access movie files on a samba server for editing in Avidemux. I cannot open the files from within the file open dialog of Avidemx because the smb network share doesn't show up. Neither can I find the gvfs mount point to navigate to the files (it used to be in ~/home/.gvfs in 12.04, then it moved to /run/user/UID/gvfs, but now in 15.10 I cannot find it anywhere. The /proc/mounts shows only "gvfsd-fuse /run/user/1001/gvfs ...." but that directory appears empty. This means that I cannot use the command line at all to fix the problem by creating a link (as I used to do in 14.04).
Any help?

Thanks,
Michael

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where is the GVFS folder in 15.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/663742/where-is-the-gvfs-folder-in-15-04)

Answer (score 0):

Force the unmount of /run/user/1001/gvfs and launch again the command

```
/usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-fuse /run/user/1001/gvfs
```

You will find your smb mounts there from now on
Don't know why automatically it does not work

Hope it helps