# gvfs mounts do not show up in ~/.gvfs

Tags: gnome, mount, gvfs

We installed the `ubuntu-desktop` on an ubuntu server installation and added `gvfs-fuse` and `gvfs-backends`.
I can now mount a smb share using `gio mount` or from nautilus.

The mount works, but it is only avaialble on `/run/user/xxx/gvfs/` and I know they should also become available in `~/.gvfs/`.

I then read from [[Why do my gvfs mounts not show up under ~/.gvfs or /run/user/<login>/gvfs?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61196/why-do-my-gvfs-mounts-not-show-up-under-gvfs-or-run-user-login-gvfs]) that I should run:

`/usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-fuse ~/.gvfs` this didn't work, since ~/.gvfs didn't exist. After creating the directory it works for me.

For new users on this machine I want to make sure that it works "out-of-the-box". I hoped that maybe this was all cause by my user existing before I installed the packages. But alas, I created a test user and it had to go through the same steps.

How can I make sure that new users do not have to go through the same steps?

Comment: *"and I know they should also become available in `~/.gvfs/`"* - where did you get that information? AFAIK that's something you would need to make happen yourself - for example by symlinking as described here: [Where can I find the mount point for SMB shares in 13.04?](https://askubuntu.com/a/343263/178692)

Comment: I have been using Ubuntu Desktop for a long while, and never had to do anything to have gvfs mounts show up in ~/.gvfs.

Comment: Fix: https://askubuntu.com/a/716071/951756

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stand corrected. I have verified that with a new install of Ubuntu Desktop the behaviour is the same.
This is just a change of behaviour. I guess I am getting old...