# 2019: Where are MTP mounted devices located in the filesystem?

Tags: usb, nautilus, android, mtp, gvfs

This is an exact duplicate of [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/342319/where-are-mtp-mounted-devices-located-in-the-filesystem), re-asked because in Ubuntu 19.10 none of the answers there work anymore. The `gvfs` directory in the terminal is always empty even though things show up in nautilus.

> I have an Android phone that connects with my computer via MTP. This
>   works fine; I can see and transfer files with Nautilus. However, I
>   often want to use the terminal to move large numbers of files, and I
>   cannot seem to find the device anywhere in the filesystem tree.
>   Nautilus reports the location as mtp://[usb:003,007]/, but it's not
>   under /media or /mnt.
>
> Does anyone know where it is?

Comment: Fix: https://askubuntu.com/a/716071/951756

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the necessary packages installed to be able to access MTP devices through Nautilus but I think you do not have the `gvfs-fuse` package installed.

If you install the `gvfs-fuse` package, when an MTP device is mounted in Nautilus you can also access it with programs not using gvfs by this path: `/run/user/$UID/gvfs/mtp:host=smartphone_hostname/`

Until you have the `gvfs-fuse` package installed, `/run/user/$UID/gvfs/` will remain empty.

Comment: That's not working for me: `mtp:host=smartphone_hostname` does not show up as a folder